# jQuery plugin isn't working in my php page, in html it's working fine

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working in an PHP coded site. In here I want to add the jQuery plugin Barousel. I tested in a HTML page outside my site and it works fine. But when I add the code in the page where it has to work (PHP), it isn't working.

In chrome I got the next message;

```
Uncaught Type Error: object#<object> has no method 'barousel'
```

[This](http://wrkspc.nl/devroedevrouw.nl/home) is the page.

The image has to be a carousel with text.

Please can anyone help me; I really don't know what to do.

Comment: look like you haven't loaded the jquiry plugin Barousel js file..

Comment: can you show the your code where u implmented the plugin

Comment: Seeing your source code, you are loading jquery 1.3.2, you should upgrade it to newer version because maybe barousel plugin use more recent functions.

Comment: try replacing  `jQuery('#barousel_itemnav').barousel({` with  `$('#barousel_itemnav').barousel({`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page head has loaded `jquery.js` twice.

The second load will overwrite the first, and `$.fn.barousel` will no longer be defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="barousel/js/jquery.barousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //BAROUSEL - ITEM NAVIGATION
        jQuery('#barousel_itemnav').barousel({
            manualCarousel: 0,
            slideDuration: 3000
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- remove this -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- remove this -->
```